# CA1307: Specify StringComparison not thrown for string.Equals(string)

Tags: c#, static-analysis, string-comparison, fxcop, static-code-analysis

I am wondering why the static code analysis (of VS 2015) will not lead to an error if you use String.Equals(string). So

```
"file".Equals("FILE")
```

does not lead to code analysis error, whereas

```
String.Compare("file", "FILE", true)
```

does lead to CA 1307 error.

The documentation for this rule says on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386080.aspx)

> Many string operations, most important the Compare and **Equals** methods, provide an overload that accepts a StringComparison enumeration value as a parameter.
>
> Whenever an overload exists that takes a StringComparison parameter, it should be used instead of an overload that does not take this parameter. By explicitly setting this parameter, your code is often made clearer and easier to maintain.

From this I would expect that the first example should lead to CA 1307 error.

So not throwing the error in that case could be very dangerous in some cases and lead to a "buggy" applications.

Am I missing something here?

If this is by design, is there any way that I can achieve the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Your compare method you are passing a boolean whereas the Compare function is expecting a StringComparison enum value.

```
String.Compare("file", "FILE", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

This should return a true response because you are ignoring case.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the answer to my question. A was asking why the first example "file".Equals("FILE") is not bringing up the CA 1307 error when the String.Comparison is not specified.